# quantum evolution transition and conditional probabilities

Tags: quantum-information, density-operator

I am trying to assess quantum information theoretic equivalents of classical conditional entropies, but of the same system at different times (i.e. transition probabilities), rather than between parts of a bipartite system.

Given that the quantum Liouville equation (or lindblad eqn) will evolve deterministically (in  the same manner as the classical Liouville eqn) one angle I am looking at is building in these 'classical' time correlations into a super-density matrix such that $\rho_{t,s}=\rho_{t|s}\otimes \rho_s$.

The main issue is that the tools of quantum information theory are geared up for entangled systems etc. But one cannot have a super-position with one's past: the evolution of the density matrix is deterministic and 'straightforward'. There are open questions regarding the building in of classical style correlations into quantum machinery which are going to be interesting or just malformed (by me).

But this approach and others (out of a few)  I cannot seem to find anywhere in the literature. Does anyone have any ideas on this issue? Or even just some references?

Comment: Quite a late comment but these references may be of interest:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03637

https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0611233.pdf